# SwiftUI: How to build a customizable timer countdown and its separate view

Tags: timer, swiftui

I saw many blogs/articles on how to build a timer with Swift UI. But I cannot figure out to get what I really want working.

The 2 main issues I am facing are:
1. My TimerView is rebuilt whenever its parent view is rebuilt due to states changing
2. I am not able to send parameters to my @ObservedObject TimeCountDown property (2 parameters: duration coming from another view, and an onEnded completion)

```
class Round: ObservableObject {
   @Publishedvar items: [Item]
   var duration: Double
   init(items: [Item], duration: Double) {
      self.items = items
      self.duration = duration
   }
}

Struct ParentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var round: Round
  @State private var isRoundTerminated: Bool = false

  var body: Some View {
    VStack {
       if isRoundTerminated {
         RoundEndView()
       } else {
         TimerView(duration: round.duration, onEnded: onTimerTerminated)
         RoundPlayView(items: round.items)
       }  
    }
 }
}

struct TimerView: View {
   @ObservedObject countdown = TimeCountDown()
   var duration: Double
   var onEnded: (() -> Void)?

   ///// I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO PROPAGATE THE onEnded completion TO countdown:TimeCountDown

   var body: Some View {
      Text("There are \(countdown.remainingTime) remaining secs")
         .onAppend() {
             timer.start(duration: duration)
             /// MAYBE I COULD ADD THE onEnded WITHIN THE start() CALL?
         }
   }
}

class TimeCountDown : ObservableObject {
   var timer : Timer!
   @Published var remainingTime: Double = 60
   var onEnded: (() -> Void)?

   init(onEnded: @escaping (() -> Void)?) {
      self.onEnded = onEnded
   }

   func start(duration: Double) {
     self.timer?.invalidate()
     self.remainingTime = duration
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1, target: self, selector:#selector(updateCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }

  @objc private func updateCount() {
     remainingTime -= 1

     if remainingTime <= 0 {
        killTimer()
        self.onEnded?()
     }
  }

 private func killTimer() {
   timer?.invalidate()
   timer = nil
 }
```

}

**However** that does not work...

I also tried to implement the following TimerView:

```
struct CountdownView: View {
   @State private var remainingTime: Int = 60
   @Binding var countingDown: Bool

   var onEnded: (() -> Void)?

   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

   init(durations: TimerDuration, onEnded: (() -> Void)?, start: Binding<Bool>) {
       self.onEnded = onEnded
       self._countingDown = start
       self.remainingTime = durations.duration
   }

   var body: some View {
       Text("Remaining \(remainingTime) secs")
           .onReceive(timer) {_ in
               if self.countingDown {
                   if self.remainingTime > 0 {
                       self.remainingTime -= 1
                   } else {
                       self.onTerminated()
                   }
               }
       }
   }

   func onTerminated() {
       timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
       self.remainingTime = 0
       onEnded?()
   }
}
```

However when the ParentView is rebuilt very often (due to modifications to round.items (@Published from Round:ObservableObject) the timer can be frozen.

Comment: Use SwiftUI's timer. It is much easier to use, and updates the views appropriately. [See more](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui)

Comment: many thanks. I tried this mechanism but it happens that the Timer is then stuck/frozen when the RoundPlayView is modifying the round.items (@Published). It triggers a rebuild of the ParentView body/initializer and the TimerView does not update.

Comment: Update your code with the SwiftUI timer.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get what you mean.

Comment: Use the SwiftUI timer I mentioned in the article I linked in my first comment. Then update your code with that, and then I can try help further.

Comment: I added it by creating a new answer below. Many thanks @George _E

Answer (score 0):

@George_E, please find below my update code (Please note that I simplified the nextWord() func (a but useless here) but it does modify the round.remainingDeck which is a Published property within the ObervableObject Round. That triggers a rebuild of RoundPlayView and that freezes the timer):

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Round: ObservableObject {
   @Published var remainingDeck: [String] = ["Round#1", "Round#2", "Round#3", "Round4"]
   var roundDuration: Int = 5
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var round = Round()

  var body: Some View {
      RoundPlayView(round: round)
  }
}

struct RoundPlayView: View {

   @ObservedObject var round: Round
   var duration: Int {
       return round.roundDuration
   }
   @State private var timerStart: Bool = true
   @State private var isTerminated: Bool = false

   init(round: Round) {
       self.round = round
   }

   var body: some View {
       return VStack {
           if self.isTerminated {
               EmptyView()
           } else {
               VStack {
                   CountdownView(duration: duration, onEnded: timerTerminated, start: $timerStart)

                   Button(action: { self.addWord() }) {
                       Text("Add words to the deck")
                   }
              }
           }
       }
   }


   private func nextWord() {
       round.remainingDeck.append("New Word")
   }

   private func timerTerminated() {
       terminateRound()
   }

   private func terminateRound() {
       self.isTerminated = true
   }
}
```

and here is my TimerView code:

```
struct CountdownView: View {
   @State private var remainingTime: Int = 60
   @Binding var countingDown: Bool

   var onEnded: (() -> Void)?

   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

   init(duration: Int, onEnded: (() -> Void)?, start: Binding<Bool>) {
       self.onEnded = onEnded
       self._countingDown = start
       self.remainingTime = duration
   }

   var body: some View {
       Text("Remaining \(remainingTime) secs")
           .onReceive(timer) {_ in
               if self.countingDown {
                   if self.remainingTime > 0 {
                       self.remainingTime -= 1
                   } else {
                       self.onTerminated()
                   }
               }
       }
  }

  func onTerminated() {
       timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
       self.remainingTime = 0
       onEnded?()
  }
}
```

Comment: Update your original answer with this by clicking the edit button. Makes it easier :)

Comment: Also, I cannot directly run this code because it contains your own types like `Round` and `TimerDuration` which I don't have. Or `RoundEndView` as well for example. Try to create a minimal example, meaning that anyone can run it but it still experiences the same issue. Helps us, helping you get an answer quicker!

Comment: @Georges_E I tried to change my code with simpler types so that it can be used.When pressing several times on the button "Add words to the deck", the Timer gets frozen.